# SQL Split comma separated list from one table and print content from second table based upon this list

Tags: php, mysql, explode

I have two tables, `rooms` and `utilities`.
In the table named `rooms`I have a coloumn also called `utilities`. This coloumn stores comma separated numbers referencing the IDs from the table `utilities`.

How can I split (explode?) the values from the `utilities` coloumn, and match them against the `utilities` table, printing the values that have matching IDs as the spitted values?

Example:

Table: rooms
|---------------|----------------|-----------------|
|     **ID**         |  **Name**        |   **Utilities**     |
|---------------|----------------|-----------------|
|        1       |   Room1      |     1,3,4      |
|---------------|----------------|-----------------|
Table: utilities
|---------------|----------------|
|     **ID**         |   **Device**      |
|---------------|----------------|
|     1           |   Speakers |
|---------------|----------------|
|     2           |   TV           |
|---------------|----------------|
|     3           |   Smart TV |
|---------------|----------------|
|     4           |Web camera|
|---------------|----------------|

I want to print something like this:
`Room1: Speakers, Smart TV, Web camera`

Here's what I have so far, confroomreport.php:

```
<?php
 require_once("db.php");
 $util = $conn->getDeviceList();
 $arr = $conn->getConfRoomList();
?>


<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Utilities</th>
    </tr>
    <?php for( $i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    print_r  ("<tr>
     <td>".$arr[$i]['name']."</td>
     <td>".$arr[$i]['utilities']."</td>
     </tr>"); } ?>
</table>
```

and in `db.php`

```
public function getDeviceList()
    {
          $arr = array();
          $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, device from utilities order by device ASC");
          $statement->bind_result($id, $device);
          $statement->execute();
          while ($statement->fetch()) {
            $arr[] = [ "id" => $id, "device" => $device];
          }
          $statement->close();

          return $arr;
    }

public function getConfRoomList()
  {
      $arr = array();
      $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, name, utilities from rooms order by name ASC");
      $statement->bind_result($id, $name, $utilities);
      $statement->execute();
      while ($statement->fetch()) {
      $arr[] = [ "id" => $id, "name" => $name, "utilities" => $utilities];
      }
      $statement->close();

      return $arr;
  }
```

**EDIT updated code based on accepted solution:**

I added this to my db.php:

```
  public function joinDevRoom()
  {
     $arr = array();
     $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT r.name,GROUP_CONCAT(u.device) FROM room r LEFT JOIN utilities u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id,r.utilities)>0 GROUP BY r.id");
     $statement->bind_result($id, $utilities);
     $statement->execute();
     while ($statement->fetch()) {
       $arr[] = [ "id" => $id, "utilities" => $utilities];
     }
     $statement->close();

     return $arr;
  }
```

and this is my updated confroomreport.php:

```
<?php
 require_once("db.php");
 $arr = $conn->getConfRoomList();
 $join = $conn->joinDevRoom();
?>


<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Utilities</th>
    </tr>
    <?php for( $i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
     print_r  ("<tr>
     <td>".$arr[$i]['name']."</td>"); }
     for( $u=0; $u < count($join); $u++) {
     print_r ("<td>".$join[$u]['utilities']."</td>
     </tr>"); } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do not store values in csv Format. Learn about normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT r.Name,GROUP_CONCAT(u.Device) FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN utilities u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id,r.Utilities)>0
GROUP BY r.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post according to this solution.